# Objective-C method with variable arguments - first argument skipped?

Tags: objective-c, foundation, variadic-functions

I'm following Stephen Kochan's Programming in Objective-C, 6th edition, and I'd like some help with this particular method. Basically I have a class, `AddressBook`, that has two instance variables: an `NSMutableArray` called `book`, and an `NSString` called `bookName`. Quite self-explanatory.

`book` holds `AddressCard`s, and I was trying to implement a method that takes multiple variables of type `id` and adds all of them to the array `book`. Here it is:

```
-(void) addCards:(id)firstCard, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, firstCard);

    id theArgument = firstCard;
    while ((theArgument = va_arg(argumentList, id)))
    {
        [self addCard:theArgument];
    }
    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

The `addCard` method is a customised implementation of `NSMutableArray`'s `addObject` method. Problem is, the first argument that I provide to `addCards` isn't added to `book`. Here is `main.m` and the accompanying output:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        AddressCard *card1 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Joseph Brown" andEmail:@"jbrown@yahoo.com"];
        AddressCard *card2 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Thomas Walter" andEmail:@"t.walter@gmail.com"];
        AddressCard *card3 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Jonathan Green" andEmail:@"jon_green@gmail.com"];
        AddressCard *card4 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Elizabeth White" andEmail:@"elizwhite@live.com"];

        AddressBook *myBook = [[AddressBook alloc] initWithName:@"My Address Book"];

        [myBook addCards:card1, card2, card3, card4, nil];

        NSLog(@"Lookup: Joseph Brown");

        if ([myBook lookup:@"joseph Brown"] == nil)
        {                                   
            NSLog(@"Not Found!");
        }

        else
        {                                   
            [[myBook lookup:@"Joseph Brown"] print];
        }
        [myBook list];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2014-06-25 11:43:25.997 AddressBook[19454:303] Lookup: Joseph Brown
2014-06-25 11:43:25.999 AddressBook[19454:303] Not Found!
2014-06-25 11:43:25.999 AddressBook[19454:303] ======== Contents of My Address Book ========
2014-06-25 11:43:26.000 AddressBook[19454:303] Thomas Walter           t.walter@gmail.com              
2014-06-25 11:43:26.000 AddressBook[19454:303] Jonathan Green          jon_green@gmail.com             
2014-06-25 11:43:26.000 AddressBook[19454:303] Elizabeth White         elizwhite@live.com              
2014-06-25 11:43:26.001 AddressBook[19454:303] =============================================
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

`lookup` does exactly that: looks up the `AddressCard` specified by the argument to it; `print` prints the `AddressCard` in a nice format; `list` also does its namesake: list the contents of `book`. Now, as can be seen in the output, `Joseph Brown`, although added to the `AddressBook` as `card1`, isn't actually added, as proved twice by the output. What's wrong?

Comment: Consider using an array instead. I've found it very challenging to debug variable arguments code. It takes three characters to wrap your list of cards in an array.

Comment: Fair enough; I did consider that at first. But aren't the elements going into an array already? I chose not to because it felt inefficient; why initialise an array to put its elements into another array? If I really needed to I could use arrayWithArray: or arrayWithObjects: to do it, I suppose. But why, exactly, besides ease of debugging?

Comment: Cleaner code, MUCH cleaner code. Also, you only need three characters to wrap your cards in an array and you don't need to bother with nil termination. `[myBook addCards:@[card1, card2, card3, card4]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution using an `NSArray`...

```
AddressCard *card1 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Joseph Brown" andEmail:@"jbrown@yahoo.com"];
AddressCard *card2 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Thomas Walter" andEmail:@"t.walter@gmail.com"];
AddressCard *card3 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Jonathan Green" andEmail:@"jon_green@gmail.com"];
AddressCard *card4 = [[AddressCard alloc] initWithName:@"Elizabeth White" andEmail:@"elizwhite@live.com"];

AddressBook *myBook = [[AddressBook alloc] initWithName:@"My Address Book"];
[myBook addCards:@[card1, card2, card3, card4]];
```

---

```
-(void)addCards:(NSArray *)cards {
    for (AddressCard *card in cards) {
        [self addCard:card];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I completely forgot about fast enumeration and Obj-C literals. For even more reduction of code, I suppose arrayWithArray: could be used?

Comment: I meant that instead of enumerating through the array of cards, you could simply do `[self.book arrayWithArray:cards];`.

Comment: That's not how arrayWithArray works... It's a static method that returns a copy of an array. You haven't shared the structure of the AddressBook class so I can't really comment on that.

Comment: You may have been thinking of `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
id theArgument = firstCard;
while ((theArgument = va_arg(argumentList, id)))
```

you did not do anything with `firstCard`. second argument overrides it

```
-(void) addCards:(id)firstCard, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, firstCard);

    id theArgument = firstCard;
    while (theArgument)
    {
        [self addCard:theArgument];
        theArgument = va_arg(argumentList, id);
    }
    va_end(argumentList);
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I should've realised that. Thanks very much.